# EntiryFramework returning wrong or outdated rows in included table

Tags: entity-framework

I'm using .NET 7.0, EF Core 7.0.3

I have a table called Order, and a related table OrderDetail. One Order can have multiple OrderDetails.

```
    [Table("Order")]
    public class OrderDto
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Column("OrderId")]
        public int OrderId { get; set; }
        public List<OrderDetailDto> OrderDetails { get; set; }
        ...
    }


     [Table("OrderDetail")]
     public class OrderDetailDto
     {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Column("OrderDetailId")]
        public int OrderDetailId { get; set; }
             
        [Required]
        [ForeignKey("OrderId")]
        [Column("OrderId")]
        public int OrderId { get; set; }

        public int? Active {get; set; }
        ...
     }
```

In my code I get the order the following way:

```
 var order = DbContext.Set<OrderDto>().Include(x => x.OrderDetails.Where(y => y.Active == 1)).FirstOrDefault(x => x.OrderId == orderId);
```

In the data set I'm trying this on, I have only one OrderDetail record. It is retrieved correctly and I can see it in the Order.OrderDetails collection.

Next I make changes to the OrderDetail, via a stored procedure call. This will create a new OrderDetail with the same OrderId. The new OrderDetail will have the Active flag set to 1, and the old OrderDetail has Active flag set to 0 (this is for history/versioning).

I can see these two rows when I run a query in the MS SQL Server Management Studio. They have the correct values (the new one has the new values) and they have Active set correctly, to 0 and 1 respectively.

Next I need to work with the new (updated) OrderDetail. So I get the order again:

```
 var updatedOrder = DbContext.Set<OrderDto>().Include(x => x.OrderDetails.Where(y => y.Active == 1)).FirstOrDefault(x => x.OrderId == orderId);
```

What happens next **is I get an order with TWO OrderDetails.** They both have the same values as in the DB (old one has old values, new one has new values) **except they both have Active set to 1.** This is obviously incorrect, only the new record should have been returned.

I was advised that this may have happened because EF can't figure out which columns are Keys, but I have the [Key] attribute in all the right places. Just to be sure I tried adding `[ForeignKey("OrderId")]` on the OrderId field in the OrderDetailDto. It didn't help.

Can anyone help?

The only other possible cause that I can think of is that maybe EF somehow has the result of the previous query cached, and when I get the Order again, even though I'm using a different oject, the old OrderDetail record is somehow appended because it's cached under the same OrderId?